# inequality on the coefficients of a $4$ degree polynomial with real roots.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ be a polynomial with $4$ non-necessarily distinct real roots $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$.

If $b\geq d+5$ what is the minimum possible value for $(x_1^2+1)(x_2^2+1)(x_3^2+1)(x_4^2+1)$?

This problem is from a competition so I think it has a cool solution.

Here is the solution I came up with but I don't like it.

Clearly we can assume $b=d+5$, so $\sum\limits_{i< j} x_ix_j+5-x_1x_2x_3x_4=0$

Then we use lagrange multipliers since partial derivatives are easy to calculate. The functions are:

$\sum\limits_{i< j} x_ix_j+5-x_1x_2x_3x_4$ and $(x_1^2+1)(x_2^2+1)(x_3^2+1)(x_4^2+1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum x_i &=&-a \\
\sum_{i \neq j} x_i x_j &=& \; \; \;b \\
\sum_{i \neq j \neq k} x_i x_j x_k &=&-c \\
x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 &=& \; \; \; d
\end{eqnarray*}
It easy enough to calculate
 \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum x_i^2 &=&a^2-2b \\
\sum_{i \neq j} x_i^2 x_j^2 &=&b^2-2ac+2d \\
\sum_{i \neq j \neq k} x_i^2 x_j^2 x_k^2 &=&c^2-2bd \\
(x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4)^2 &=&d^2
\end{eqnarray*}
So the quantity of interest is 
 \begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x_1^2)(1+x_2^2)(1+x_3^2)(1+x_4^2) &=& 1+a^2-2b+b^2-2ac+2d+c^2-2bd+d^2 \\
&=& 1+(a-c)^2 +(b-d)^2 -2(b-d)
\end{eqnarray*}
So the minimal value will be attained when $a=c$ and $b-d=5$ ... the value will be $\color{red}{16}$.

EDIT : It remains to show that a polynomial exists (as has been done in dxiv's solution). The specific values $a=4$ and $b=6$ will give $(x+1)^4=0$ where the minimal value is attained.

Comment: very nice, thank you!

Comment: you just forgot to prove that a polynomial of the form $x^4+ax^3+bx^3+ax+(b-5)$ with all roots real exists.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative hint:  let $y=x^2+1\,$, then $\prod (x_k^2+1)=\prod y_k$ and the problem reduces to minimizing the constant term of the monic quartic satisfied by $y\,$.

To derive the equation in $y$ one can use polynomial [resultants](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+x%5E4+%2B+a+x%5E3+%2B+b+x%5E2+%2B+c+x+%2B+d,+y+-+x%5E2+-+1,+x+%5D+for+y+%3D+0), otherwise doing it by hand:

$$
x^4+bx^2+d = - x(a x^2+c) \\
(x^4+bx^2+d)^2 = x^2(a x^2+c)^2 \\
g(y) = \big((y-1)^2+b(y-1)+d\big)^2 - (y-1)\big(a(y-1)+c\big)^2 = 0
$$

The constant term is $g(0) = (1-b+d)^2+(a-c)^2 \ge (1-5)^2+0=16$ with equality iff $a=c$ and $b=d+5$.

The lower bound of $16$ is attained for $a=c=4,b=6, d=1$ corresponding to the polynomial $x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1=(x+1)^4\,$ with all roots equal to $-1$, so $16$ is indeed a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

$$\prod_{k=1}^4(x_k^2+1)=\prod_{k=1}^4|x_k+i|^2=|\prod_{k=1}^4(x_k+i)|^2=$$
$$=|d-b+1+(a-c)i|^2=(b-d-1)^2+(a-c)^2\geq(5-1)^2+0^2=16.$$
The equality occurs for all $x_k=1$, which says that $16$ is a minimum.

Done!